# SQL Unique Key Violation

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I am getting Unique Key violation and I am not sure why, here is my scenario.
I have a table with the following fields:

```
ID, LocationID, Name, Description, Dewey
```

The `ID` is obviously the primary key, `LocationID` is a foreign key linked to the `Location` table and the other fields are simply `varchar` fields with no relationship associated with them.

When I insert a row where the `LocationID` and `Name` have the same value as another row in the table I get this error:

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX_InternalLocation'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.InternalLocation'. The statement has been terminated.

If either of those fields is different I can insert the record no problem. This seems weird to me as neither of these rows is the unique identifier for the table.

It appears for some reason the DB thinks together the fields form a key but that is not how it should be and when I look at the table properties that is not how it is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do check what the definition of IX_InternalLocation is, or rather post the whole table definition here.

Comment: It's possible for a table to have more than one unique key/index, and it sounds like that is the case here.

Comment: a down vote? really why would you down vote this questions??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this query:

```
SELECT tc.Constraint_Name, cc.Column_Name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS tc
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cc 
   ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = cc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'IX_InternalLocation' AND tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'Unique'
```

against your database.

You should get as result:

```
Constraint_Name                  Column_Name
----------------------------------------------------- 
IX_InternalLocationDateMexri     LocationID 
IX_InternalLocationYpallhlosId   Name
```

which means there is a `UNIQUE INDEX` placed on those two columns, prohibiting any duplicate pair insertion.

Comment: Yes you are correct! This table was created by someone else and this constraint was added.  Does to changes in out system this now needs to be removed.  Thanks for your help!